# How to show fetched data from springboot on my angular frontend on input field

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular.
I build a springboot backend witch is fetching data from a extrenal API.
Now I want to display this in my Angular frontend.
The problem is that my incomming url in Angular has a input field.
Is there anyone how can help me explain how to handle this?

I made a service in angular, and a component for displaying the data, but I'm not quite sure if I'm doing it the right way.

Comment: What have you done already? Impossible to help without code samples from both backend and frontend.